# WSO2 ERROR - PropertyHelper Error invoking setter method named

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I recently upgraded from WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 to WSO2 EI 6.3.0. Things seemed to be working fine until I deployed an existing project and now I am receiving the following error:

`ERROR - PropertyHelper Error invoking setter method named : setSourceIsRemote() that takes a single String, int, long, float, double or boolean parameterargument type mismatch`

This is the existing code:

```
<class name="com.hms.mediator.SFTPMediator">
    <property name="sourceHost" value="myhost"/>
    <property name="sourcePort" value="22"/>
    <property name="sourceUser" value="username"/>
    <property name="sourcePassword" value="pw"/>
    <property name="sourceFilter" value="*\.*"/>
    <property name="sourceIsRemote" value="true"/>
    <property name="deleteFromSource" value="false"/>        
    <property name="archivePath" value="/archive/"/>
    <property name="destinationPath" value="/destination/"/>
    <property name="sourcePath" value="/sourcePath"/>
</class>
```

The issue happens when a boolean value is being set, in this case, `sourceIsRemote` and `deleteFromSource`. This works correctly on the older version.

Has anyone else come across this issue and is there a solution besides going to an earlier version of WSO2?

Answer (score 0):

In Your class Mediator you have to create the setter and getter methods for the variable name declared in your class mediator.

> Note: The variable value must follow the same name in your sequence and also the same variable name

For example my class mediator

```
public class RequestValidator extends AbstractMediator {

    private String tokenVariable = "tokenVariable";

    private String passVariable = "passVariable";

    @Override
    public boolean mediate(MessageContext mc) {
    }
}
```

In my sequence

```
<class name="mediator.RequestValidator">
 <property name="tokenVariable" value="$ctx:authRequest"/>
</class>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in one of the core classes in synapse core that prevents from setting the boolean type values in the mediators. I have provided the fix for it. In the mean-while if you are still having this issue use the attached jar ( with the fix) to replace the original one (synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v80) in the lib folder (../wso2/wso2ei/6.4.0/wso2/components/plugins/).

Link: https://github.com/OmerQ/WSOFixJar/blob/master/synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v80.jar