# WSO2 EI 6.4.0 Class Mediator to pass boolean value - ERROR: PropertyHelper Error invoking setter method named :

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am trying to pass Boolean variable to wso2 class mediator like below.

passing values to class mediator:

```
<class name="com.cts.in.jubilant_service.ParseEmailBody">
   <property expression="$ctx:INC_Match" name="INC_Match"/>
   <property expression="$ctx:SR_Match" name="SR_Match"/>
</class>
```

WSO2 Class Mediator Code:

```
public class ParseEmailBody extends AbstractMediator {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Jubilant_ParseEmailBody.class.getName());

    private boolean SR_Match;
    private boolean INC_Match;

    public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) {
        logger.info("===Inside ParseEmailBody Class Mediator===");

        logger.info("***SR_Match ****" + SR_Match);
        logger.info("***INC_Match****" + INC_Match);

        if (SR_Match) {
            logger.info("***Inside Service Request****");
        } else if (INC_Match) {

            logger.info("***Inside Incident****");
        }

        return true;
    }

    //setter,getter method for SR_Match

    public boolean isSR_Match() {
        return SR_Match;
    }

    public void setSR_Match(boolean SR_Match) {
        this.SR_Match = SR_Match;
    }

    //setter,getter method for INC_Match

    public boolean isINC_Match() {
        return INC_Match;
    }

    public void setINC_Match(boolean INC_Match) {
        this.SR_Match = INC_Match;
    }

}
```

But Unfortunately the below ERROR i got.

```
PropertyHelper Error invoking setter method named : setINC_Match() that takes a single String, int, long, float, double or boolean parameterDid not find a setter method named : setINC_Match() that takes a single String, int, long, float, double or boolean parameter
```

As of now i am getting boolean value inside class mediator like below which works fine.

```
boolean INC_Match=Boolean.valueOf((String)context.getProperty("INC_Match"));
boolean SR_Match=Boolean.valueOf((String) context.getProperty("SR_Match"));
```

Already referred below link which doesn't resolve my issue:
[Ref link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210892/wso2-error-propertyhelper-error-invoking-setter-method-named)
[Ref link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65662477/how-to-pass-boolean-property-to-class-mediator-in-wso2-ei)

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong the way of doing in setter, getter method or shall i use `Boolean.valueOf(String)`?

Comment: Maybe it is just a question typo, but the class name from class mediator `com.cts.in.jubilant_service.Jubilant_ParseEmailBody` is not the same as the provided java class name `ParseEmailBody`. Maybe another different mediator is being executed.

Comment: Hi @usuario
Thanks for your suggestion.
typo in raising question in stack overflow. not in code. anyway i edited question. now kindly check and let me know what i did wrong